# Kernel Boot over NFS

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs, root-filesystem, kernel-panic

I'm trying to boot the 4.13.0-rc2 mainline kernel on the Beaglebone Black (rev C) with `omap2plus_defconfig` over NFS. I've enabled `CONFIG_NFS_ROOT` along with the following options:

```
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFS_V2=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
CONFIG_NFS_SWAP=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_2=y
CONFIG_PNFS_FILE_LAYOUT=y
CONFIG_PNFS_FLEXFILE_LAYOUT=m
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1_IMPLEMENTATION_ID_DOMAIN="kernel.org"
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1_MIGRATION=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_SECURITY_LABEL=y
CONFIG_ROOT_NFS=y
# CONFIG_NFS_USE_LEGACY_DNS is not set
CONFIG_NFS_USE_KERNEL_DNS=y
# CONFIG_NFSD is not set
```

I'm using `nfs-kernel-server` with this [/etc/exports](https://pastebin.com/hBV94CfL). Here is an [excerpt](https://pastebin.com/zmCSncKR) from the boot log and my u-Boot session. I've enabled `nfsrootdebug` in the kernel command line but it doesn't look like it has any effect. `journalctl -xe` on the NFS server side [does indicate attempts](https://pastebin.com/P3mEgNJ9) to access the directory but the boot log doesn't print anything at all.

What could be causing this? How can I get more debug information to zero in on the cause?

Comment: Strange. Why does it say "bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=192.168.0.1, rootpath=" in the boot messages, when it obviously tries to boot from the correct path of the right server?

Comment: @Philippos I've also tried modifying the cmline to say `ip=192.168.0.100:192.168.0.1::255.255.255.0:board:off` when it does indicate the server IP as the bootserver but doesn't seem proceed.

Comment: I had similar issue booting my board. After providing `v3` option to nfs it worked well and I stopped investigating it any further.

Comment: @UVV That did the trick! If you make it an answer, I can accept it. I also found this suggestion at  https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/LinuxRootFilesystemUsingNFSVersion3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason a lot of boards with u-Boot based bootloader don't like NFSv4. If you add `v3` option to nfs it should work well. Of course, this needs to be investigated further, but due to lack of time I was not able to find the reason for that.